# How do I create this table using HTML table tags?

Tags: html, html-table, tags, tabular

How do I create this table using HTML table tags?

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like something where a table is an appropriate data structure to use.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this could be used:

```
<table border=1 width="100%" height="20%">
  <tr><td colspan="2" width="50%"></td><td width="25%"</td><td width="25%" rowspan="3"></td></tr>
   <tr><td width="25%" ></td><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sketch: when possible I would remove all of those constraints to `width`s and `height`.

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;width:100%}
table,td{border:1px solid #000}
td{height:5em;width:25%}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```